# Could not retrieve label of a custom field with Azure DevOps API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm integrating our product with Azure DevOps but currently I could not retrieve the label of custom field. I cannot use the name property because the name does not reflect the change from Azure DevOps.

I'm using "https://dev.azure.com/{organize}/{projectId}/_apis/wit/fields/Custom.NewHungField" API for getting information about the custom field, but it does not return label of the field.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can not find label when you use [Fields - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/fields/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) directly. But you can see the label of the custom fileds using [Work Item Types - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20item%20types/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1).

For more information, you can check below demo:

[image]

Using API:

`GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitemtypes/{type}?api-version=5.1`

Get the response:

[image]

You can find the label of custom fields in it.